# How to swap the data source associated with a Linq query?

Tags: c#, linq

I have read in other answers how the paramters of a linq query can be changed at runtime. But is it possible to change the data source that the query browses through *after* the query has been created? Can perhaps the query be given an empty wrapper in which data sources can be plugged in and out, unbeknownst to the query?

For example, let's assume this situation:

```
// d1 is a dictionary
var keys =  from entry in d1
            where entry.Value < 5
            select entry.Key;
```

Now, let's assume rather than modifying d1 I want myQuery to stay the same, except I'd like it to process an entirely new dictionary, d2.

The reason for this is that I'd like to decouple who provides the query from who provides the data source. I.e. think the dictionaries as metadata associated with services and the query as the mean for the consumers of services to discover which set of services match their criteria. I need to apply the same query to the metadata of each service.

I guess one parallel that I'm (maybe erroneously) making is with Regular Expression: one can compile a regular expression and then apply it to any string. I'd like to do the same with queries and dictionaries.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Can you show some pseudo-code explaining what you're after?

Comment: I'm not positive, but it sounds like you may be looking for Object-relational Mapping (ORM).

Comment: LINQ to Objects, or some other form...?

Comment: Added some context/example as requested...

Comment: @manu3d updated to show you a more standard option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A LINQ query is really nothing other than a method call.  As such, you can't "reassign" the object to which you've already called a method after it's been setup.

You could simulate this by creating a wrapper class that would allow you to change what actually gets enumerated, ie:

```
public class MutatingSource<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
     public MutatingSource(IEnumerable<T> originalSource)
     {
         this.Source = originalSource;
     }

     public IEnumerable<T> Source { get; set; }

     IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
     {
         return this.GetEnumerator();
     }

     public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
     {
        return Source.GetEnumerator();
     }
}
```

This would allow you to create the query, then "change your mind" after the fact, ie:

```
var someStrings = new List<string> { "One", "Two", "Three" };

var source = new MutatingSource<string>(someStrings);

// Build the query
var query = source.Where(i => i.Length < 4);

source.Source = new[] {"Foo", "Bar", "Baz", "Uh oh"};

foreach(var item in query)
    Console.WriteLine(item);
```

This will print `Foo`, `Bar`, and `Baz` (from the "changed" source items).

---

Edit in response to comments/edit:

> I guess one parallel that I'm (maybe erroneously) making is with Regular Expression: one can compile a regular expression and then apply it to any string. I'd like to do the same with queries and dictionaries.

A query is not like a regular expression, in this case.  The query is translated directly into a series of method calls, which will only work against the underlying source.  As such, you can't change that source (there isn't a "query object", just the return value of a method call).

A better approach would be to move the query into a method, ie:

```
IEnumerable<TKey> QueryDictionary<TKey,TValue>(IDictionary<TKey,TValue> dictionary)
{
    var keys =  from entry in dictionary
        where entry.Value < 5
        select entry.Key;
    return keys;
}
```

You could then use this as needed:

```
var query1 = QueryDictionary(d1);
var query2 = QueryDictionary(d2);
```

Comment: Hmmmm. I think the wrapper example is the right answer to the question. Wrapping the query into a method is a bit more problematic in the context I mentioned above of consumers wanting to find matching services. I feel that for security reason the more declarative path offered by linq would be more appropriate than arbitrary compiled code. But perhaps that's something that can be addressed with an immutable dictionary? At which point I guess I wouldn't even need the linq query anymore. I'm thinking aloud here. Must give it some further thought. The first part of the answer is certainly valid.

Comment: @manu3d The first part is the only attempt to actually address the question directly.  However, the second is still likely a better approach.  Even if your users are inputting parameters, you can build up queries via LINQ with the user's parameters (ie: add a where clause), etc.